# Directory Listing shows instead of Rails App - Passenger Apache CentOS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, centos, cpanel

I have a CentOS 6 server, with cPanel, Apache, Passenger, Ruby, and Rails installed.

My websites are hosted using cPanel.

When I go to `mysite.org/mysuburi`, I get the directory listing of the public directory of the rails app (/myrailsapp/public), instead of the rails app itself.

Here is my **/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost my.ip.add.ress:80>
  ServerName mysite.org
  ServerAlias www.mysite.org
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.org
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mysite.org combined
  <IfModule log_config_module>
    <IfModule logio_module>
      CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mysite.org-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  ## User mysite # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        UserDir enabled mysite
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/mysite/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup mysite mysite
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule concurrent_php.c>
    php4_admin_value open_basedir "/home/mysite:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
    php5_admin_value open_basedir "/home/mysite:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !concurrent_php.c>
    <IfModule mod_php4.c>
      php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/mysite:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/mysite:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
      php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/mysite:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup mysite mysite
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid mysite mysite
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID mysite mysite
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mysite/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>

  Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/mysite/mysite.org/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

(Notice the last line in the main block, denoting more configuration)

My **/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/mysite/mysite.org/rails.conf**:

```
RailsEnv development
RackEnv development

<Directory /home/mysite/rails_apps/myrailsapp/public>
        Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

RailsBaseURI /mysuburi

Alias /mysuburi /home/mysite/rails_apps/myrailsapp/public
<Location /mysuburi>
        PassengerBaseURI /mysuburi
        PassengerAppRoot /home/mysite/rails_apps/myrailsapp
</Location>

<Directory /home/mysite/rails_apps/myrailsapp/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        Require all granted
</Directory>

PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
```

My **/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf**:

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/passenger.conf"
```

My **/usr/local/apache/conf/passenger.conf**:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.21
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

Output of **`ruby -v; rails -v; passenger -v`**:

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.4
Phusion Passenger version 5.0.21
```

I have also symlinked the public directory of my app to a subfolder in my public_html folder as follows:

`/home/mysite/rails_apps/myrailsapp/public /home/mysite/public_html/mysuburi`

Output of **`passenger-status`**:

```
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 0
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

I'm at my wit's end... can anybody help me solve this head-scratcher?

**UPDATE:** Had two versions of passenger installed. I uninstalled both and reinstalled 5.0.21, then updated the passenger.conf file. Still having the same issue, with the same configuration and output.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found this answer on serverfault which saved my day:
https://serverfault.com/questions/731814/apachepassenger-not-serving-the-root-of-the-sinatra-application

He suggested to disable the load of the autoindex_module due to a bug in Apache 2.4.17 in combination with Passenger, which worked for me.

Comment: I'm not using that module. I don't even have it installed. I can try disabling other modules though... I'm currently using: `httpd.exp`  `libphp5.so`  `mod_bwlimited.so`  `mod_disable_suexec.so` `mod_security2.so`  `mod_suphp.so`

Comment: Sorry, it's a no-go... thanks for bringing this to my attention, though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it randomly started working. I had opened a support ticket with MediaTemple (the provider of my server) giving all these details, and the next day it was working. I have received no feedback, so I don't know what was done. I asked them what they did to fix it, and if they tell me, I'll post it here.